# Azure devops variable groups in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a variable defined in Azure devops variable group like below:

```
apple-prod-branch  refs/heads/release-823T0709
```

The above variable works when called in azure pipeline powershell command when called like:

```
"Write-Host $(apple-prod-branch)" 

Output is: 
refs/heads/release-823T0709
```

In the above variable name apple-prod-branch, apple is the repo name. How can I use the repo name and use a variable like this ?

```
$repo_name = "apple"

"Write-Host $($(repo-name)-prod-branch)"
```

End result needs to be

```
refs/heads/release-823T0709
```

Comment: Is this being queue from the appl repository or is this something where a value needs to be reference to a specific version of a separate repo?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use the repo name and use a variable like this ?

You can use the following PowerShell Script:

```
$test = "$(repo-name)-prod-branch"

$branch= [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($test)

echo $branch
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the below error. `At C:\agent\_work\_temp\54b8dea2-f26e-4281-bc85-e37f4c2bcffa.ps1:3 char:6
+ $repo-name = "apple"
+      ~~~~~
Unexpected token '-name' in expression or statement.
At C:\agent\_work\_temp\54b8dea2-f26e-4281-bc85-e37f4c2bcffa.ps1:3 char:1
+ $repo-name = "apple"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator 
must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a 
property.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`

Comment: This is my powershell step in the pipeline:  `$repo-name = "apple"

$test = "$(repo-name)-production-release-branch"

$branch= [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($test)

echo $branch `

Comment: I purpose here is to store the repo names using azure devops api in an array and check if the variable format like  `$(repo-name)-production-release-branch` exists in the variable group.